# Xamarin 'Hello Android' Quickstart fails to initialize Nexus 5 KitKat in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Being brand-new to this, I carefully followed all steps of the QuickStart at http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/

From the Visual Studio 2015 toolbar, I launch the Xamarin Android Player for Nexus 5 and this fails with a VBoxManage command problem as shown here:
[image]

The Vstudio Output Window shows the following in the Xamarin Diagnostics log:

```
    [I:sdk]:                  Looking for Android SDK..
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path does not contain adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\android-sdk-windows).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\MonoAndroid\PrivateAndroidSdkPath not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path found:
    Path contains adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]:                  Looking for Android NDK..
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack.exe in \. (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10e\).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory not found.
[I:Unknown]:              Found Android SDK. API levels: 15, 19, 21, 22, 23
[I:Unknown]:              Found Xamarin.Android 6.0.0
```

As far as I can tell, I have the latest versions of Xamarin and the Xamarin Android Player. I have searched extensively on their forum and elsewhere and I am very disappointed with this component of VS 2015. The "emulator" hurdle seems extraordinarily confusing and problematic. Hope someone can help me before trial expires.

Comment: What happens when you launch `Nexus 5 (KitKat)` from Xamarin Android Player directly?

Comment: Same result as described above (i.e. launching "directly" from XAP brings up same emulated screen and same error).

Comment: Do you have hardware emulation enable in the BIOS? Also, what version of Windows are you using and what version of VirtualBox?

Comment: Thanks. It was the AMD-V not enabled. See answer where I fleshed out some details for future rookies.

Answer (score 1):

Someone from Xamarin support guided me as follows:

- Open the Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager (from program tree, installed
  as part of Xamarin Android Player).
- Right-mouse on the machine image
  that was failing with the above symptom Choose show log..
- Saved each log as a separate file and sent .zip of them to support
- Somewhere in one of these files, AMD virtualization was shown as **DISABLED**
- **SOLUTION**: Enable AMD-V in the BIOS and reboot and retest.  Nexus 5
  emulator works properly now.